# Can't Retrieve Webcam Frame with OpenCV when using Irrlicht

Tags: c++, opencv, irrlicht

When I use OpenCV library alone (or with pure OpenGL) I am able to successfully retrieve a camera frame from my webcam and show it using a GLUT window, for example. However, when I perform the exactly same procedure using Irrlicht as a rendering engine, I am always getting empty frames. Does anyone has any ideas why this is happenning?

```
while(device->run())
{
    if( cv::waitKey(50) >= 0 ) break;
    if( !capture.grab() )
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to grab camera grame\n";
    }
    capture >> camera_frame;

    if( ! camera_frame.empty() )
    {
        unsigned char *tex_buf = (unsigned char*)frame_tex->lock();
        unsigned char *frame_buf = camera_frame.data;
        // Convert from RGB to RGBA
        for(int y=0; y < camera_frame.rows; y++) {
            for(int x=0; x < camera_frame.cols; x++) {
                *(tex_buf++) = *(frame_buf++);
                *(tex_buf++) = *(frame_buf++);
                *(tex_buf++) = *(frame_buf++);
                *(tex_buf++) = 255;
            }
        }
        frame_tex->unlock();

        driver->beginScene(true, true, SColor(255,100,101,140));

        driver->draw2DImage(frame_tex, core::rect<s32>(0,0,WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT),
            core::rect<s32>(0,0,WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT));

        smgr->drawAll();
        guienv->drawAll();

        driver->endScene();
    }
}

device->drop();
```

If I put the code between (including) beginScene and endScene outsite the camera frame emptyness test, my mesh will be rendered properly, but no camera frame will be show (the frame remains empty).

Comment: Same here, imload also fails when invoking irrlicht before.